# XAML binding with rules

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

In XAML I can set TwoWay binding to the local settings using the following

```
<TextBox
    Name="TextXYZ"  
    Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, 
            Path=TextXYZ, 
            Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="" 
    Name="checkBox1" 
    IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, 
            Path=checkBox1, 
            Mode=TwoWay}" />
<CheckBox Content="" 
     Name="checkBoxSaveSettings" 
     IsChecked="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, 
     Path=checkBoxSaveSettings, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Is it possible to introduce rules to the binding in XAML so that if `checkBoxSaveSettings.IsChecked=true` then controls will have twoway binding but if `checkBoxSaveSettings.IsChecked=false` then the binding mode is another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with `DataTrigger` like so:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=TextXYZ, Mode=OneWay}"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=checkBoxSaveSettings, Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=TextXYZ, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Your method however sounds somewhat confusing for the user as you can change control value but it won't take effect until some other `CheckBox` it ticked. I would recommend binding `IsEnabled` to `checkBoxSaveSettings.IsChecked` like so:

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, Path=TextXYZ, Mode=TwoWay}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkBoxSaveSettings, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

Comment: I always want the current control value to be used, however, the `checkBoxSaveSettings.IsChecked=true` is a setting to determine if the changed control values are saved in the Settings when changed.

Comment: That's fine. If you have a way to get current control value then first solution should work

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but there are options for this.  Here's just one.  Create a converter on your binding.  For the converter parameter, pass in the checkbox checked value.

```
<TextBox
    Name="TextXYZ"  
    Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Settings.Default}, 
            Path=TextXYZ, 
            Converter={StaticResource foo},
            ConverterParameter = {Binding ElementName="checkBoxSaveSettings", Path="IsChecked",
            Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Then create a converter called "foo" (whatever you want). Inside it, if the parameter is true, you return the value passed in.  If the parameter is false, you can return whatever you want, including the Settings.Default.TextXYZ value so nothing changes.

Another possible option is to incorporate a setter on TextXYZ but only apply the passed value to the private _TextXYZ if some other condition is true.  That other condition would be bound to the checkbox IsChecked.  That's something that should be done in a ViewModel and not an object class, but it would work in either.